# A 50 kW carrier is to be modulated to a level of 85%. What is the carrier power after modulation?

Tags: power-electronics, amplitude-modulation

I'm getting answer as 36.73KW but in the book its given as 50KW.
My calculation :

- P(total) = P(carrier)(1+(m^2)/2)
- 50 = Pc(1+.85*.85/2)
- Pc = 36.73KW.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The book is actually correct .It is a IQ test or a trick question .The modulating power goes into the sidebands so if it is just carrier power it will be 50Kw irrespective of the modulation % as long as it is linear and off course less than or equal to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming plain old amplitude modulation, the average power will just stay constant regardless of modulation index unless the transmitter experiences nonlinearities (e.g. clipping). The transmitter will transmit at 50 kW + 50 kW * 85% = 92.5 kW during positive peaks of the signal and at 50 kW - 50 kW * 85% = 7.5 kW during negative peaks, but it averages out in the long run to 50 kW.

Double sideband suppressed carrier and single sideband transmitters are a different story, as the power output does change with the modulation index in those cases.